# In Kotlin, how do I create an instance of a class where the class name is a variable?

Tags: kotlin

I am writing a Graph class in Kotlin. Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.*

class Graph<Class>(connectionProb: Double) {
    // a general network class
    val nodes = mutableListOf<Class>()
    val connectionProb = connectionProb
    val connections = hashMapOf<Class, MutableList<Class>>()

    var nextID = 0

    private fun createNode() {
        // Here is where I need help
    }
}
```

I want to be able to specify the node type for each Graph. The code above will compile, but I'm unsure how to initialize new nodes. The only argument I want to pass into each node, regardless of its type, is `nextID`.

Thanks!

Comment: Variable is variable, field is field and class is class. Please ask clearly.

Comment: This seems like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): although it's _possible_ to construct a class by name (using reflection), that's rarely a good idea, and here there are far better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is define a `class` for your `graph` `node`, and instead of maintaining a `map` for connections, let every node maintain a list of its connections.
So your `code` would look like this

```
class Graph<T>(connectionProb: Double) {

var nextId = 0
val nodes = mutableListOf<Node<T>>()

// Define a node class, so if you have graph of Integer then you want a node of Integer
class Node<T>(var id: Int){
    val connections = mutableListOf<Node<T>>()

    fun addConnection(newConnection: Node<T>){
        connections.add(newConnection)
    }

    override fun toString() = "$id"
    /** add other functions, such as remove etc */
}

fun createNode(){
    var newNode = Node<T>(nextId++)
    nodes.add(newNode)
}
```

}

Now to use this `graph` you will do followig

```
fun main(){
    var myGraph = Graph<Integer>(10.9)
    myGraph.createNode()
    myGraph.createNode()
    myGraph.nodes[0].addConnection(myGraph.nodes[1])

    /* Print all nodes in graph */
    for(node in myGraph.nodes) print("  $node")

    /* Print connections of first node */
    for(node in myGraph.nodes[0].connections) print("\n\nConnection id: $node")
}
```

Please note that this will give you a general idea of how to go about implementing graph and there are many things that you can improve in the implementation. To learn more I suggest you read a good book, such as [Data Structures and Algorithms in Java](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Data+Structures+and+Algorithms+in+Java%2C+6th+Edition-p-9781118771334)